# programming c threaded io

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

Hi what i want to do is read from a text file do something to the text and write it back out to a file. I need it to be threaded so all 3 party can run at the same time. I am trying to use a buffer to read in to and a buffer to write out from but cant work it out.

My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

char inBuf[1000];
//char outBuf[];

void *readerFun(void *meg){

char *inputFile;
FILE *input_ptr;


inputFile = (char *) meg;

input_ptr = fopen(inputFile, "r");

if(input_ptr == NULL){
    printf("%s\n", inputFile);
    printf("input file not working\n");
    return;
}

while(!feof(input_ptr)){

    fscanf(input_ptr, "%s", &inBuf);
     sleep(1);
//  printf("%s\n", &inBuf );
//  printf("test _____________\n" );



}





return NULL;
}


void *modifierFun(void *meg){

//char c;
//while((c = getc(inBuf) != EOF)){

//strcat(outBuf, c);

//}

//}


return NULL;
}


void *writerFun(void *meg){

char *outFile;
FILE *output_ptr;

outFile = (char *) meg;

output_ptr = fopen(outFile, "a");

while(inBuf != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", inBuf );
fprintf(output_ptr, "%s", inBuf);
}

return NULL;
}

 int 
     main (int argc, char **argv){

        pthread_t reader, modifier, writer;
        char *meg = argv[1];
        char *meg2 = argv[2];
        int ret1, ret2, ret3;

        ret1 = pthread_create(&reader, NULL, readerFun, (void *) meg);
        ret2 = pthread_create(&modifier, NULL, modifierFun, (void *) meg);
        ret3 = pthread_create(&writer, NULL, writerFun, (void *) meg2);



        pthread_join(reader, NULL);
        pthread_join(modifier, NULL);
        pthread_join(writer, NULL);

        return 0;

     }
```

Would be a big help is someone could point me down the right road. I have looked all over the net and cant really find what im looking for.

Comment: parallelizing file I/O isn't really worth it. Even if you code it, it won't make the app run faster (often you'll get the opposite effect).

Comment: Pawel is right -- you probably won't see much (if any) speedup from multithreading the I/O, because the bottleneck will be your hard drive, which won't go any faster just because multiple threads are using it at once.  OTOH, if you want to do the multithreading just as an exercise, you can implement that by setting up a message-passing system (e.g. using dequeues, mutexes, and condition variables or pipes for signaling).  E.g. reader thread reads some data, passes it in a message to the modifier thread, which modifies it and passes it in a message to the writer thread, and so on.

Comment: Pawel and Jeremy are correct.  Actually, in this scenario, non-blocking i/o would be more efficient than multithreading since the majority of the time the application will be waiting for i/o.  This avoids the complexity in coordinating across multiple threads, but you still need to manage multiple file descriptors in the single thread.